# Does REDIM PRESERVE for more elements set all new elements to NOTHING?

Tags: vb.net

I have an array with data.
I do REDIM PRESERVE and specify a larger boundlist.
All old elements are preserved.

Will all new elements be NOTHING?

```
REDIM PRESERVE my_array( my_array.LENGTH + 10 )
```

Will the new 10 elements all be NOTHING?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, additional elements are `Nothing`. Be aware, though, `ReDim Preserve` does not just extend an array in-place. It allocates a completely new array and copies the existing elements, and then leaves the original for the garbage collector.

Almost all cases where you find yourself using `ReDim Preserve` should be changed to use a generic `List(Of T)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Joel.  I'd always assumed as such, but was leery about all cases, as I could find no mention in Docs.Microsoft REDIM page. This would indeed be a performance issue, but is negligible in my case.

Comment: Agreed in principal, but no time to re-code and re-test large complex app.  That's why I've used Visual Basic for 35 years -- better optimized for rapid development than anything else besides Forth.